# how do _mobile_* divs gets populated with html data when viewing a prestashop page in mobile

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to understand how prestashop works regarding mobile displays.

I noticed in the used template, the `header.tpl` file contains the following html divs for mobile:

```
 <div class="float-xs-right" id="_mobile_language_selector"></div>
            <div class="float-xs-right" id="_mobile_user_info"></div>
            <div class="float-xs-right" id="_mobile_cart"></div>
            <div class="float-xs-right" id="_mobile_currency_selector"></div>
```

I also noticed that once I remove any of the components (for example the shopping card) from `theme.yml`:

```
global_settings:
  configuration:
    PS_IMAGE_QUALITY: png
  modules:
   to_enable:
     - ps_linklist
  hooks:
    modules_to_hook:
      displayNav1:
        - ps_contactinfo
        - tuxinmodaccessibility
      displayNav2:
        - ps_languageselector
        - ps_currencyselector
        - ps_customersignin
    REMOVE THIS LINE ->>>    - ps_shoppingcart
      displayTop:
```

then the cart component is not displayed in the navbar. so the mobile and deskop version required this configuration to be set.

I noticed also that for each component besides having main div with `_mobile_` prefix, there are also divs with `_desktop_` prefix.

I'm trying to find out how to properly add my accessibility component to the navbar and that it will also be displayed on mobile.
so far it displays only on desktop and not on mobile so I was guessing that I need to add something like

```
<div class="float-xs-right" id="_mobile_tuxinmodaccessibility"></div>
```

no idea how to implement it properly.

I don't quite understand how for example, how this process works for `mobile_cart` div while the module name is `ps_shoppingcart`.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to checkout [themes/classic/_dev/js/responsive.js](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/themes/classic/_dev/js/responsive.js) file.

Comment: Can you expand on this? *Why* does he need to checkout the responsive.js file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the theme.js file.
Script moves contents between desktop and mobile HTML elements in DOM. Every HTML element with ID that starts with `id="_mobile_"` gets content from corresponding desktop variation that starts with `id="_desktop_"` (if you inspect DOM in mobile view you'll notice that desktop elements got empty).

```
function o() {
    u.default.responsive.mobile ? (0, s.default)("*[id^='_desktop_']").each(function(t, e) {
        var n = (0, s.default)("#" + e.id.replace("_desktop_", "_mobile_"));
        n.length && r((0, s.default)(e), n)
    }) : (0, s.default)("*[id^='_mobile_']").each(function(t, e) {
        var n = (0, s.default)("#" + e.id.replace("_mobile_", "_desktop_"));
        n.length && r((0, s.default)(e), n)
    }), u.default.emit("responsive update", {
        mobile: u.default.responsive.mobile
    })
}
```